# Flask redirect stops working after one try?

Tags: python, flask

When I run flask with `python test.py`, and then navigate to http://localhost:5000 in my browser, I would expect the terminal to read:

`test-1 test-2 test-3`

The three print statements ONLY appear when `test.py` is run for the first time.  After that, the terminal will only show:

`test-1 test-2`

For some reason, the redirecting to the second page is not occurring after the initial run.  Is there some sort of weird caching nonsense going on?  Can someone please explain what is happening?

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():

    print('test-2')
    return redirect(url_for('page2'))

@app.route('/secondPage')
def page2():

    print('test-3')
    return send_from_directory('.', 'test_dashboard_4.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('test-1')
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: why do you not have an `app.run()` ?

Comment: So this code clearly won't run. Please post a working example.

Comment: Good catch.  I added in `app.run()`.  The `sys.exit()` was simply to terminate the program, fixed that too.

Comment: Not sure if the numbering changed after app.run was added. When I run it I see test-1, test-2, test-3. Then test-2, test-3 as expected.

Comment: @bren, did you restart the flask script between runs?

Comment: Yes, restarted or not I get the same results when revisiting `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I was finding lying around and I found this question is old and no answers yet.
So I will be the one who *may* help you.

Use `render_template` and put all of your htmls to templates folder. Something like this

```py
import flask

app = flask.Flask("My life sucks")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.render_templates('your html page here.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

One other thing, you can't put javascript to same directory where html was.
Instead put it in static folder and add static to where you import javascript like.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Hello world!
    </h1>
    <script src="static/hi.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is javascript file if you want to see something

```js
console.log("I get imported!");
document.body.innerHTML += '<p>:D</p>'
```

Here's the tree

```
D:.
│   app.py
│
├───static
│       hi.js
│
└───templates
        index.html
```